# sqlite error parsing query

Tags: xcode, cocoa, sqlite, parsing

I'm receiving a strange error querying a database with sqlite:
`SQLlite error: near "SE": syntax error`
I don't really get why he doesn't like the query string I'm sending to it. Here's my code:

```
-(Wallet*)loadDataFromSQL{
    sqlite3 *database;
    NSLog(@"opening..");
    if (sqlite3_open([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mywallet.sqlite3"] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"opened..");
        const char *query = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM 'Transaction';"] UTF8String]; // "insert into \"Transaction\" values (\"2013-01-01\",\"tipo\",\"cat\",1)";
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        NSLog(@"preparing stmnt..");
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, &selectstmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Prepared..");
            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSLog(@"row..");
                NSString *data = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (char*)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];
                NSString *type = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (char*)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];
                NSString *category = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (char*)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
                float amount = (float)sqlite3_column_double(selectstmt, 0);

                Transaction *t = [[Transaction alloc]init:data transactionType:type transactionCategory:category transactionAmount:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",amount]];
                NSLog(@"%@",t);
            }
        }else{
            NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"SQLlite error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database)]);
        }
    }
    sqlite3_close(database); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.
    return nil;
}
```

Nothing too fancy.. what's wrong with it?
Thanks!

Comment: Please learn C properly before getting into Objective-C - `[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mywallet.sqlite3"]` could be reduced to `"mywalled.sqlite3"`... The query string as well. Also, there's a reason `NSLog()` accepts printf-style formatting, `NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:whatever]`)` is redundant and insecure.

Comment: SQLite uses [ANSI SQL quotes](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q24). `'Transaction'` is an invalid identifier. Try `"Transaction"`.

Comment: @H2CO3 you're the reason why this kind of websites are so usefull! <3

Comment: @pst I already tried both but nothing changed :/

Comment: @Eux I'm here to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of [sqlite3_prepare_v2](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) must be the length of the query string, or just `-1`.

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, &selectstmt, nil)
```

With SQLite complaining about "`SE`", I'd guess that the value of `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` is `2`. `:-)`